# Prove that $\sum\nolimits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \cdot ({\sqrt n \over 2n+3})$ is convergent

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need to prove that $\sum\nolimits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \cdot ({\sqrt n \over 2n+3})$ is convergent. My approach so far, using the leibniz criterion

1. $|(-1)^n \cdot ({\sqrt n \over 2n+3})|$ is convergent. I have proven that already.
2. $|a_{n+1}| \leqslant |a_{n}|$

I'm having problems with 2. Im stuck at:

${\sqrt{k+1} \over 2k+5} \leqslant {\sqrt{k} \over 2k+3}$

How should I continue from here on?

Comment: Square both sides, and multiply by denominators. You should get an inequality of degree $2$.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(n)=\frac{\sqrt n}{2n+3}\implies f'(n)=\frac{3-2n}{2\sqrt n(2n+3)^2}$$

So for $n>2$, $f'(n)<0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** for the second point.
Let $$f(x)=\frac{x}{2x^2+3}$$

$$\implies f'(x)=\frac{3-2x^2}{(2x^2+3)^2}$$

$\implies f $ is decreasing at $[2,+\infty)$

$$\implies a_n\;:\;n \mapsto \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2n+3}=f(\sqrt{n})$$ is decreasing for large enough $n$.

Answer (score 1):

> **Note that we only require that $\frac{\sqrt k}{2k+3}$ monotonically decreases for values of $k\ge K$ for some $K$.**

---

First, the inequality $\displaystyle \frac{\sqrt{k+1}}{2k+5}\le \frac{\sqrt k}{2k+3}$ is equivalent to the inequality $$\left(1+\frac1k\right)^{1/2}\le 1+\frac{1}{k+3/2} $$

---

Next, applying [Bernoulli's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli's_inequality), we find that

$$\left(1+\frac1k\right)^{1/2}=\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac1k\right)^{-1/2}}\le 1+\frac{1}{2k-1}$$

---

Finally, inasmuch as $1+\frac1{2k-1}\le 1+\frac{1}{k+3/2}$ for $k\ge3$, we find that

$$\displaystyle \frac{\sqrt{k+1}}{2k+5}\le \frac{\sqrt k}{2k+3}$$

for $k\ge 3$.  And we are done!

Comment: I see nothing wrong (+1)